# linking addresses to subdir

Tags: php, .htaccess

I own two http:// addresses. They both link to the same place, the home dir of my server. As my host doesn't give me the option to have the second address link to a sub dir, I was wondering if I could set this up myself using php or htaccess or something?

The two addresses are totally different, so maybe having as bit of code "read" what address was used or something? Hope this makes sense.

**EDIT**
So: say I have www.a.com and www.b.com both link to the main folder my host space.
Now I want www.a.com to keep linking there, but I want www.b.com to link to a subdir /public_html/b

Maybe thats a bit more clear. Thanks!

Comment: You don't own http:// addresses, you own domain names :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could route requests to the two domains to different folders using RewriteRules:

```
RewriteRule .? - [E=HOST:%{HTTP:Host}]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HOST} =1.example.com
RewriteRule (.*) /1.example.com/public_html/$1

RewriteCond %{ENV:HOST} =2.example.com
RewriteRule (.*) /2.example.com/public_html/$1
```

Comment: This seems to be about subdomains. I have say abc.com and def.com which both go to the abc.com main dir. I want def.com to go to abc.com/def/ (or def.com/def/

Comment: Just remplace 1.example.com and 2.example.com by what you want. There is no technical difference between a domain and a subdomain.